# What is runtime error (NZEC) in Java?

Tags: java, error-handling, ide, coding-style

Here is the [code challenge question](https://www.codechef.com/SEPT17/problems/CHEFSUM) I am working on.

And my code is:

```
import java.io.*;

class NEW {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
       BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       long[] a;
        a = new long[15];
       long n,temp=0,num = 0;
       int x=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
       for(int j=0;j<x;j++)
       {
           n=Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
           for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
           {
               if (i==0)
               {
                   temp=num;
               }
             num=Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
             if (i==0)
               {
                   temp=num;
                   a[j]=i+1;
               }
             if(temp>num)
             {
                 temp=num;
                 a[j]=i+1;
             }

           }


       }
       for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
       {
           System.out.println(a[i]);
       }
    System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

It's working fine in NetBeans 8.2, but when I try to upload this, it gives a message "Runtime error (NZEC)".

Comment: [mcve]. Add the stack trace to the question. And give the line that is called out in the exception.

Comment: Why do you use System.exit(0)?

Comment: NZEC is Non Zero Exit Code. Please check this discussion (https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/19677/how-to-get-rid-of-getting-nzec-error-while-submitting-solution-in-java)

Comment: really i can't understand what u want to say.means what I have to do now?

Comment: I can omit " System.exit(0)".but it also give me same result

Comment: i hv tried try catch block ..but it also gives me same error